# Alamofireimage (Swift3) Ambiguous reference to member 'download(

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

Hi guys i am trying to download a bunch of images in my app using the Alamofireimage library. this is the code that i use and it is basically what they have in their documentation:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()
    for (img):(ImageData) in imgDownloadList
    {
        let urlRequestx = img.downloadUrl
        downloader.download(urlRequestx){ response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            debugPrint(response.result)

            if let image = response.result.value {
                print(image)
            }

        }

    }
```

i got the error

> Ambiguous reference to member
>   'download(_:receiptID:filter:progress:progressQueue:completion:)'

did someone face the same problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `img.downloadUrl` a `URLRequest`?

Comment: damn, i feel super stupid now! Thanks a lot, it was a string. my bad. Thanks again!